# Lists, conditionals and loops don't give the result expected

Tags: python, indexing

I am pretty sure that it must be something stupid, but it has been many hours without getting why it isn't working and now I have to know.

I know how to get the result in another way, but I'd like to learn the mechanics of why this way isn't working.

```
word="patata"
indeces=[]

for letter in word:
    i = word.find(letter)
    if i in indeces:
        start = indeces.index(i)
        index=word.find(letter,start)
        indeces.append(index)
    else:
       indeces.append(i)


print indeces
```

The thing is that I want the list `indeces` with the index of every letter, but it can't be twice even the letter is the same one.

Comment: So what's your expected output and which output do you get instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Your code gives `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` - what did *you* expect? Are you trying something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24845188/3001761), to get `[4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]`?

Comment: do you just want the index of all letters?

Comment: How about `indeces = range(len(word))` ? If that is what you want instead.

Comment: This looks like a classic XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you think you want the indexes of all the letters?

Comment: You say *"I know how to get the result in another way"* - what is the result, and what is that other way?

Comment: That's correct jonrsharpe, I am getting [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1] but I don't want them to repeat, so I'd like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]. That is why with the conditional it should check if the number is already in the list, and if so, start checking from the number already in the list, but I don't know why it ins't working.

Comment: @miindlek already pointed out the Python built-in that makes this *so much easier*. Or even `i = 0; for letter in word: indeces.append(i); i += 1` would do it!

Comment: yes yes, I know and I am agree. but, when I have trying this for so long I just want to know what is not working in that way. I must be missing something

Comment: @miindlek that's not the only problem - fixing that alone would give `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3]`

Comment: `for ind,letter in enumerate(word):` and  `index=word.find(letter,ind)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
i = word.find(letter)
```

always finds the first occurrence of `letter` in `word`, and this line:

```
start = indeces.index(i)
```

always finds the first occurrence of `i` in `indeces`. Then, this line:

```
index=word.find(letter,start)
```

*includes* `start`, so just finds the same letter straight away!

The only way to make your current code work would be to introduce a `while` loop, and start *after* the last occurrence:

```
for letter in word:
    i = word.find(letter)
    while i in indeces:
        i = word.find(letter, i+1)
    indeces.append(i)
```

This keeps looking until it finds a new `i` for the current `letter`. If `i` isn't in `indeces` to start with, the loop never runs.

---

That being said, this is a hugely inefficient approach; if you want the indices use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
>>> range(len("patata"))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and if you want the letters and their indices use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> list(enumerate("patata"))
[(0, 'p'), (1, 'a'), (2, 't'), (3, 'a'), (4, 't'), (5, 'a')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! All this explanation has been really useful. I have just get started with programming last month and learning on your own can be difficult.